# An upper bound on diagonal k-colored Ramsey number

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I need a reference on any upper bound on $R(n, n, \dots, n)$ with $k$ arguments.
For example, the standard recurrent bound gives something like $k^{kn}$, but I cannot find any written explicit bound.

Comment: You can get $k^{kn}$ by restricting to the largest coloured neighbourhood of an arbitrary vertex $kn$ times, then doing a second pass to get $n$ vertices where all the forward edges are the same colour.